# TKinter process is not drawing Labels, Buttons, and Entry Fields... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a full time student, taking my first class in python.
This is so strange, it was working, and now, it is no longer showing the buttons, labels, and entry fields. I'm sure it was something I removed or added, but, I'm at a loss.
Any ideas?  All suggestions are appreciated.

```python
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
import tkMessageBox

class BouncyGUI(Frame):
    """The GUI used to interface with the bouncy calculation from chapter 9 section 1."""

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        # Establish the Base Frame
        self.master.title("Calculate the Bounciness of a Ball")
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.master.grid()
        self.master.resizable(0,0)

        # Establish the components for capturing the Height
        self._heightLabel = Label(self, 
                                  text = "Height of initial drop:",
                                  justify = "left")
        self._heightLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self._heightVar = DoubleVar()
        self._heightEntry = Entry(self,
                                  textvariable = self._heightVar, 
                                  justify = "center")
        self._heightEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        # Establish the "bounciness index"
        self._bouncyIndex = Label(self, 
                                  text = "Bounciness Index:",
                                  justify = "left")
        self._bouncyIndex.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self._bouncyVar = DoubleVar()
        self._bouncyEntry = Entry(self,
                                  textvariable = self._bouncyVar,
                                  justify = "center")
        self._bouncyEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self._bouncyVar.set(0.6)

        # Establish number of allowable bounces
        self._numberBounces = Label(self, 
                                    text = "Number of Bounces:",
                                    justify = "left")
        self._numberBounces.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self._numberBouncesVar = IntVar()
        self._numberBouncesEntry = Entry(self,
                                         textvariable = self._numberBouncesVar,
                                         justify = "center")
        self._numberBouncesEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        # Establish a field for the response
        self._answer = Label(self, 
                             text = "Distance Travelled",
                             justify = "left")
        self._answer.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self._answerVar = DoubleVar()
        self._answerFont = tkFont.Font(weight="bold", size = 12)
        self._answerEntry = Entry(self,
                                 textvariable = self._answerVar,
                                 justify = "center",
                                 font = self._answerFont)
        self._answerEntry.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        self._answerEntry.config(state = DISABLED, bg = "green")

        # Create frame to hold buttons
        self._buttonFrame = Frame(self)
        self._buttonFrame.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

        # Create Reset Button
        self._buttonReset = Button(self._buttonFrame,
                                   text = "Reset",
                                   command = self._reset,
                                   width = 15,
                                   padx = 2,
                                   pady = 2)
        self._buttonReset.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        #self._buttonReset.config(state = DISABLED)

        # Create Calculate Button
        self._buttonCalc = Button(self._buttonFrame,
                                  text = "Calculate",
                                  command = self._calculate,
                                  width = 15,
                                  padx = 2,
                                  pady = 2)
        self._buttonCalc.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        #self._buttonCalc.config(state = NORMAL)

    def _reset(self):
        """Allow for the screen to reset for fresh data entry."""
        self._heightVar.set(0.0)
        self._numberBouncesVar.set(0)
        self._answerVar.set(0.0)
        #self._buttonCalc.config(state = NORMAL)
        #self._buttonReset.config(state = DISABLED)
        #self._numberBouncesEntry.config(state = NORMAL)
        #self._bouncyEntry.config(state = NORMAL)
        #self._heightEntry.config(state = NORMAL)

    def _calculate(self):
        """Calculate the bounciness and update the GUI"""
        if self._validDataTypes():
            self._answerVar.set(computeDistance(self._heightVar.get(), \
                                                self._bouncyVar.get(), \
                                                self._numberBouncesVar.get()))
            #self._numberBouncesEntry.config(state = DISABLED)
            #self._bouncyEntry.config(state = DISABLED)
            #self._heightEntry.config(state = DISABLED)
            #self._buttonCalc.config(state = DISABLED)
            #self._buttonReset.config(state = NORMAL)

    def _validDataTypes(self):
        theMessage = ""
        if self._isInt(self._numberBouncesVar.get()) != True:
            theMessage += "Please re-enter Integer Value for Number of Bounces.\n"

        elif self._isFloat(self._bouncyVar.get()) != True:
            theMessage += "Please re-enter Float Value for Bounciness Index.\n"

        elif self._isFloat(self._heightVar.get()) != True:
            theMessage += "Please re-enter Float Value for Initial Height."

        if len(message) > 0:
            tkMessageBox.showerror(message = message, parent = self)
            return False
        else:    
            return True

    def _isInt(self, value):
        # Test to ensure that value entered is an integer
        try:
            x = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            # If not return false
            return False

        # if it is an integer, return true
        return True

    def _isFloat(self, value):
        # Test to ensure that value entered is a float value
        try:
            x = float(value)
        except ValueError:
            # If not return false
            return False

        # If it is a float, return true
        return True

def computeDistance(height, index, bounces):
    """Compute the distance travelled."""
    total = 0
    for x in range(bounces):
        total += height
        height *= index
        total += height
    return total

def main():
    """Run the main program"""
    BouncyGUI().mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grid the main app, not just call its mainloop:

```
def main()
    app = BouncyGUI()
    app.grid()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `main()` function setup code isn't working properly.  I'm not sure how you had it set up before, but one way to get it working is this:

```
def main():
    """Run the main program"""
    root = Tk()
    gui = BouncyGUI()
    gui.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in your code when compiling:

```
NameError: global name 'message' is not defined
```

Comment: I noticed that after I submitted it.  Thanks. The message = message should read message = theMessage